# Convert two 8-bit uint to one 12-bit uint

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit

I'm reading two registers from microcontroller. One have 4-bit MSB (First 4-bits has some other things) and another 8-bit LSB. I want to convert it into one 12-bit uint (16 bit to be precise). So far I made it like that:

```
UINT16 x;
UINT8 RegValue = 0;
UINT8 RegValue1 = 0;

ReadRegister(Register01, &RegValue1);
ReadRegister(Register02, &RegValue2);

x = RegValue1 & 0x000F;
x  = x << 8;
x = x | RegValue2 & 0x00FF;
```

is there any better way to do that?

/*** To be more precise ReadRegister is I2C communication to another ADC. Register01 and Register02 are different addresses. RegValue1 is 8 bit but only 4 LSB are needed and concatenate to RegValue (4-LSB of RegValue1 and all 8-bits of RegValue). */

Comment: "better" in which sense? It depends on what is important to you, e.g. portability, speed, code density ...

Comment: I think  you want `x = x | (RegValue & 0xFF)`

Comment: @Esailija: `&` has higher precedence than `|`.

Comment: @undur_gongor speed and less variables. For example, instead using RegValue,RagValue1 and x - just write into one UINT16

Comment: A decent compiler should figure out what you are actually doing (triggered by the shift-by-8) and generate close-to-optimal code by e.g. just copying an 8 bit value instead of performing 8 shift operations. This depends on the target platform, its word size, and its instructionset, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `RegValue & 0x00FF` mask is unnecessary since RegValue is already 8 bit.

Breaking it down into three statements may be good for clarity, but this expression is probably simple enough to implement in one statement:

```
x = ((RegValue1 & 0x0Fu) << 8u) | RegValue ;
```

The use of an unsigned literal (0x0Fu) makes little difference but emphasises that we are dealing with unsigned 8-bit data.  It is in fact an `unsigned int` even with only two digits, but again this emphasises to the reader perhaps that we are only dealing with 8 bits, and is purely stylistic rather than semantic.  In C there is no 8-bit literal constant type (though in C++ `'\x0f'` has type `char`).  You can force better type agreement as follows:

```
#define LS4BITMASK ((UINT8)0x0fu)

x = ((RegValue1 & LS4BITMASK) << 8u) | RegValue ;
```

The macro merely avoids repetition and clutter in the expression.

None of the above is necessarily "better" than your original code in terms of performance or actual generated code, and is largely a matter of preference or local coding standards or practices.

Comment: _The RegValue & 0x00FF mask is unnecessary since RegValue is already 8 bit._ You are right - it's unnecessary

Comment: Note that using `LS4BITMASK` is rather pointless from the compiler's point of view, @PawelZ. `&` causes integer promotions, so the bit operations are performed on `int`s [by the as-if rule, if the hardware allows bit operations on 8-bit types, those may be used, provided they yield the same result as if `int` were used]. Without the cast to `UINT8`, the mask `0x0Fu` would cause the operations to be performed on `unsigned int`. The values aren't shifted right, it should be obvious to the compiler that `(RegValue1 & 0x0Fu) << 8` is representable by an `int`, both should lead to the same code.

Comment: @Daniel:  I am pretty sure I made it clear that it does not generate *better translation*.  However it is arguably better human readable code.  Many coding standards require "magic numbers" to be avoided, and I have probably spent too long "cleaning-up" code through static analysis.  I was originally going to mention the implicit casts involved, but decided that it might only serve to confuse.

Comment: Ah, dang. I _had_ written that it's only useful for readability by humans, but I was over the comment length limit and deleted that part. Sorry for the wrong impression caused by the deletion, it was just meant as an elaboration of what does and does not happen with that cast.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the endianness of your machine, you can read the bytes 
directly into `x` like this:

```
ReadRegister(Register01, (UINT8*)&x + 1);
ReadRegister(Register02, (UINT8*)&x);
x &= 0xfff;
```

Note that this is not portable and the performance gain (if any) will 
likely be small.

Answer (score 0):

If the registers are adjacent to each other, they will most likley also be in the correct order with respect to target endianness.  That being the case they can be read as a single 16 bit register and masked accordingly, assuming that `Register01` is the lower address value:

```
ReadRegister16(Register01, &x ) ;
x &= 0x0fffu ;
```

Of course I have invented here the `ReadRegister16()` function, but if the registers are memory mapped, and `Register01` is simply an address then this may simply be:

```
UINT16 x = *Register01 ;
x &= 0x0fffu ;
```